# Android webservice authentication

Tags: android, web-services, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I want a web service to enhance my app. However - I'm unsure what the best way to handle regitration/authnetication is. I don't want my users to sign up but it would be nice if I somehow could use Androids built in user-account to authenticate the device to the service.

It should of course be secure, and multiple devices should authenticate as the same user (provided they are logged in with the same google account of course)

Comment: Did you have a look at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae? What data would you want to send between device and web server?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/). With Endpoints, you expose an OAuth 2-protected API on your backend, and connect to it from a client library for Android. Users will be able to sign in (without entering passwords), and have one account across devices (if they use the same Google account).

There are example [backends](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) and [clients](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android) on github.

Comment: Looks very promissing. I'll get back to you when I'm sure it can do what I need